# Hovering issues with products image in magento

Tags: magento

In Magento,I am not able to see the product's image in the front end but when I hover the cursor over the product the image just slides in through the left which looks very bad. Can any one please help me how to fix this problem?

Comment: is check box is enabled under `catalog > Manage Products > Images`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?